# Oracle - Updating table based on field from another table

Tags: oracle, sql-update, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have a Task table and a Project table. I'm trying to update the Percent Complete field in the Project table with the value of the Percent Complete field from the Tasks table. But I only want to update the field when the sequence code from the Task table is equal to 1. My failed attempt looks like this:

```
UPDATE inv_projects prj
SET prj.percent_complete = (SELECT NVL(tsk.prpctcomplete, 0)
                            FROM prtask tsk
                            WHERE tsk.prprojectid = prj.prid)
WHERE (SELECT tsk.prwbssequence
       FROM prtask tsk
       WHERE prj.prid = tsk.prprojectid) = 1;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
...
Error report -
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want the sequence filtering in the subquery, like so

```
UPDATE inv_projects prj
SET prj.percent_complete = (
    SELECT NVL(tsk.prpctcomplete, 0)
    FROM prtask tsk
    WHERE tsk.prprojectid = prj.prid AND sk.prwbssequence = 1
)
```

This assumes that `(prprojectid, prwbssequence)` is unique in the task table, which seems consistent with your problem statement.

If there are projects without a task of sequence `1`, and you don't want to update them, then use `exists`:

```
UPDATE inv_projects prj
SET prj.percent_complete = (
    SELECT NVL(tsk.prpctcomplete, 0)
    FROM prtask tsk
    WHERE tsk.prprojectid = prj.prid AND sk.prwbssequence = 1
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM prtask tsk
    WHERE tsk.prprojectid = prj.prid AND sk.prwbssequence = 1
)
```

Or maybe your intent is to set the completion percent to `0` in this case; if so, move `NVL()` outside of the subquery:

```
UPDATE inv_projects prj
SET prj.percent_complete = NVL(
    (
        SELECT tsk.prpctcomplete
        FROM prtask tsk
        WHERE tsk.prprojectid = prj.prid AND sk.prwbssequence = 1
    ),
    0
)
```

Comment: Your second block is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much.